# Highcharts stock chart overflow above of yAxis lable

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, overflow

I'm created a stock chart by highcharts library but the chart line is above the yAxis label.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZeroOne,
try use code below to align yaxis labels to left.

```
yAxis: [{   
          labels: {
                 align: 'left',
          },
}]
```

Comment: Hey koshad. But I want the label on the right.

Comment: Hi ZeroOne, 
you can ofset xaxis by ofset.
yAxis: [{   
         offset: 50,
}]

Comment: Please edit the answer and add the offset thing in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `offset` and `labels.y` properties:

```
    yAxis: {
        offset: 35,
        labels: {
            y: 3
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nkwdh0te/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.offset

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.labels.y